# Adding an event listener with applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to do a little hack with the Messages application on `OSX Mountain Lion`. I am using applescript, but everything I have tried has not been working out for me..

Here is what I tried first

```
using terms from application "Messages"
   on message sent theObject
        display "it worked!"
   end message sent
end using terms from
```

But when I press run it just seems to just exit to program immediately. How do I make it stay in listener loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the answer to this question... which I believe is completely unintuitive.
Basically, first you move the script to `~/Library/Scripts/Messages`, then in `Messages` create an alarm for the event and have the event call the script.